# Using printf %q to pass arguments with spaces

Tags: bash, printf, whitespace

Suppose I have a script that prints out the number of arguments passed to it:

```
# file: num_args

echo "Number of arguments: $#"
```

Now my question pertains to the following invocations:

```
> ./num_args a b c
> Number of arguments: 3 # As I would expect.

> ./num_args "a b c"
> Number of arguments: 1 # As I would expect.

> ./num_args a\ b\ c
> Number of arguments: 1 # As I would expect.

> printf "%q\n" "a b c"
> a\ b\ c                # As I would expect.

> ./num_args $(printf "%q" "a b c")
> Number of arguments: 3 # NOT as I would expect.
```

Given that the `printf` man page states that

```
 %q     ARGUMENT is printed in a format that can be reused as shell input, escaping non-printable characters with the proposed POSIX $'' syntax.
```

I am not sure what happens in the last case above.

Comment: "Reused as shell input" if it goes through all parsing stages. Unquoted expansions *don't*. This has nothing to do with `printf %q`, and everything to do with [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In that case, I wouldn't be able to wrap the $(printf ...) call in quotation marks, would I?

Comment: Correct, wrapping it in quotation marks doesn't help you either. `eval "./num_args $(printf "%q" "a b c")"`, on the other hand, does what you expect (but is [code one should be wary of writing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)).

Comment: `printf "%s\n" $(printf "%q" 'a b c')` may give you more insight into what exactly is happening, especially in combination with Charles's link.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not sure I understand why wrapping the `$(printf ...)` in quotes won't help. I just tried `printf "%s\n" "$(printf "%q" "a b c")"`, and it printed a single line consisting of `a\ b\ c`, which unless I'm misreading the question is the desired behavior. Do not all shells work this way?

Comment: @MikeHolt, as I understand it the desired output is a single line containing `a b c`, without the backslashes. That is to say, the OP wants the syntax added by `printf %q` to be *consumed* as syntax, and that requires eval.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ahh, ok. That makes much more sense. I was hung up on the number of arguments and missed the point that the slashes were not part of the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf %q` output is escaped correctly to be *parsed as source code by a shell interpreter*.

However, unquoted expansions aren't parsed as source code; they go only through string-splitting and glob-expansion phases. (This is a Good Thing: Otherwise handling untrusted filenames or other potentially-dangerous content in shell scripts would be nearly impossible).

You can substitute this output into a shell command, as in `sh -c "...$foo..."` or `eval "...$foo..."` or `ssh somehost "...$foo..."`; it can't (shouldn't) just be used unquoted.

---

Some important references:

- [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) explains why strings containing source code can't be used by expanding them unquoted.
- [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) explains the risks involved in using `eval` (one of the families of workarounds discussed above).